# Where should I install the TFS 2013 Test Controller?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Should I install the TFS Test Controller on the same machine as the Build Controller?
and also let it launch the browser on this same machine?

What is the best practice?

We have a TFS 2013 Build Controller on a local machine.
We have CodedUI tests which launch a browser which we want to get going again (worked on tfs2010).

Also where exactly do I get the installer for the Test Controller? I presume its inside the TFS 2013 server ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you can install test controller and build controller on the same machine. You can consider installing build agent on a different machine than TFS Application Tier for performance consideration especially you would like to set up some Gated Check-in or CI builds.

In addition, as you would like to run Coded Ui test, you should configure the test agent to interact with the Desktop. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee291332(v=vs.120).aspx

In addition, you can download the Test Controller here. (Both test controller and test agent included) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750